# accessing an instantiated sealed class public member

Tags: c#, .net, sealed, class-instance-variables

i am trying to instatiate a public `sealed` class in my program,

the thing is, ...as i am still fresh `C# .net`  <sub>**not-yet**</sub>  Developer ,  i find this issue a little difficult ...

As for the problem in Question, you can skip straight to Program example, or read the folowing background:

DB_Schema is a  helper `namespace`, i've Created, to deal with the data accessing

(it holds `tables` And `SP`s names ..etc')

one of its classes(below) deals with `Stored Procedures`, and this one holds names of SPs Parameters

```C#
public sealed class SProc
{
    public sealed class GetCPAReport
    {
        public const string RecordNum = "@RecordNum",
                            CPAColumnName = "@CPAColumn_Name",
                            Value = "@value",
                            IsFreelance = "@isFreelance";
    }

}
```

- **Usage in program:**

within method for data access via SP

```C#
private DataTable Get_RefTable_OfUsersBy(string DepartmetID)
{
    SProc.GetCPAReport SProcGetCpa = SProc.GetCPAReport();
    SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SProcGetCpa.IsFreelance, 1));
}
```

trying to access one of  the instance (`SProcGetCpa`) members is not possible the way i tried .

i could just make class `SProc` + it's sub class `UpdateCPAReport`  **not**  `sealed` and ...

**but** as i was searching the question "**can sealed class be instantiated?**

well.. the answer is **Yes** ... though trying to find information on the error:

***cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead***

yields no results, Nor an Example of **Accessing Instantiated `sealed class` public member** code 
atleast not for fresh .net C#arpers like me

### - **Update**

i wanted to avoid  long lines and make custom short names for the strings that represents the stored procedure name

instead of

```
ParListEmployeeUsrs.SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(HTSPs.RobTC_CPA_Users_Names_JobPosition.IsFreelance, SelectedDepartmentID));
```

**update 2**

for future comers on this subject who seeks for an answer

*as suggested by a dear friend of ours, here in StackOverflow*

if you do have to make a short namings for your classes, when using them for current peoject :

just place this among the `using`*s* of your project

```C#
using system...
using restOf.net
//just add your own as follows !

using shortClassName = myHelperNameSpace.MyIncrediblyUnnecessaryLongHelperClassName;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetCPAReport` doesn't *have* any instance members. `const` members are implicitly static. In C#, you can't access static members through a reference as you're trying to at the moment.

You just want:

```
SP_Params.Add(new SqlParameter(SProc.GetCPAReport.IsFreelance, 1));
```

Personally I'd make `GetCPAReport` a *static* class, too. There's no point in instantiating it, as it just contains constants... so actively prevent it from being instantiated.

Comment: i guess i get a little over Excited ,over using the `sealed` modifier i got a little bored with static

Comment: @LoneXcoder No, you should just treat them as static since they effectively are, instead of making them instanced.  Also keep in mind static classes are also effectively sealed.

Comment: @LoneXcoder: Why would you want to make them *instance* members at all? They're constants. Put it this way: would you ever expect one instance of `GetCPAReport` to have a different value for `IsFreelance` from other instances?

Comment: @JonSkeet the names here been translated its all 20 letters or so in length (:

Comment: Such as : `HTSps.RobTC_CPA_Users_Names_JobPosition_Field` = * 5 params = five long lines , i hate them (even though i am using 42" Led screen)'

Comment: @JonSkeet (iv'e Updated my question) would you think it's something i should not realy think of ? the names of the fields/const/properties are long... reason?: some times when you have many of them (too many), they differ by some extra `different` words to tell you who they are and what they do , so i wanted to try and keep it short when i **use** those in application

Comment: @LoneXcoder: That shouldn't affect your design. If you *really* want to make things shorter, you could use aliasing `using` directives... but you shouldn't make something an instance member just for the sake of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for your attention mr SKeet, i was woried you might think it's a kind'a Nonsense issue and it's not even something to put in mind but i do care of how the code looks the  : googling "aliasing using directives"

Comment: @JonSkeet but offcorse (: , i knew about the `using` statement{applied with `namespace` *s* and.. types that are implicitly `idisplosable convertible` Capable ! (don't mistake and think i'm good student... as i knew about `using`, and what it is exactly ... only by trial & error !! (: ) } , as i am trying to learn while working(Low pay but paied job (: ) ..seem that is not the best idea for get ejucated as opposed to - taking **step by step** online tutorial as if i were in a College).. that explains my lack of knowlege of the `alias` part ...